# Out of range error when converting long? to datetime

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, long-integer

I'm trying to convert a date that comes from the DB as long? into datetime, but I get a out-of-range error.

This is the date, 26/09/2014 12:00:07 and this is what I get from the DB, 201409261200442886.

This is the code I'm testing.

```
long DBdate = 201409261200070892;
DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime date = start2.AddMilliseconds(unixDate2).ToLocalTime();
```

Any  ideas??

Comment: You say "Unix date" as if the value was a Unix time stamp. It's not. 201409261200070892 appears to be 2014-09-26 12:00:07.0892. Converting this to milliseconds is right out.

Comment: Unixdate is just a name. It doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because 201409261200070892 is not a number of milliseconds, it's the digits of the year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds and (presumably) fractional seconds concatenated. You'll need to write code to parse it like that.

Comment: Ok, and how do I do that??

Answer (score 0):

Datum = st.Datum == null ? string.Empty : DateTime.ParseExact(st.Datum.ToString().Substring(0, 14), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(),